# Does Error object have literal syntax?

Tags: javascript, literals

I found so far that most fundamental objects have literal syntax

**Numeric literal** is a sequence of digits 453

**String literal** consists of characters enclosed in quotes. "yes"

**Boolean** type has two literal values: true and false.

**Object literal** is a list of name and value pairs in curly braces {}

**Array literal** is a list enclosed in square brackets [].

**Function literal**, synonym for function expression var add = function
   (a, b) {return a + b}

**Date** objects have no literal syntax.

**RegExp literal** is a pattern enclosed between slashes var re = /abc/;

**Error** objects have no literal syntax???

Symbol has no literal syntax.

Also Promise has no literal syntax (maybe later?)

Please confirm is it true that Error can be created only with new and it has no literal syntax

Comment: `Error` has no literal syntax.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error so like what does it contain? Object with message, name, etc?

Comment: @Xufox, yes. Good point. I'll remove my comment since it is probably misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing inherently special about the `Error` class in JavaScript - it's a class just like any other that *by convention and specification* is the base class for errors generated by the language and from the standard APIs.

The `throw` keyword doesn't even require that the argument passed to `throw` be an instance of an `Error`.  You can `throw "error"` and the string will be what's passed to the `catch` block.

Consequently, there's no special literal syntax for it.   It is not however necessary to use `new` - you can just call `Error(msg)` and it will return a newly created object for you.